# Обработка сообщений для иконки в трее в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, winapi

Задача состоит в том чтобы консольное(обязательно) приложение сворачивалось в трей. То есть окно скрывалось, а в трее появлялась иконка, по нажатию на которую окно снова отображалось. Скрытие окна и создание иконки проблем не доставили, а вот с нажатием на иконку возникла проблема. Как я понял, сообщения консольного окна обрабатываются отдельным процессом(или чем то там) так что их получить нам нельзя а значит нет смысла привязывать иконку к консольному окну и нужно создать обычное(невидимое, но существующее) и делать его обработчик событий. В интернете ничего толкового не нашел. По разным сайтам собрал такой вот код, но иконка в таком случае начинает пропадать при наведении мыши(то есть уже не кликнуть):

```
...
void createTrayIcon()
{
HINSTANCE instance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
WNDCLASSEX notify = { 0 };
notify.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
notify.hInstance = instance;
notify.lpszClassName = TEXT("Main");
notify.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
RegisterClassEx(&notify);
const HWND g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("PlaceholderWindow"), nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                   HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, instance, nullptr);

NOTIFYICONDATA *data = new NOTIFYICONDATA{};
data->uID = 1234;
data->hWnd = g_hWnd;
data->uFlags = NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
data->hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
data->uCallbackMessage = WM_USER;
_tcscpy(data->szTip, _T("Сервер работает"));
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD,  data);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
    case WM_USER:
        if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            std::cout << "Icon clicked" << std::endl; //тут будет код разворачивания

        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Как заставить иконку сидеть на месте? И что еще нужно сделать, чтобы по нажатию на иконку окно получило сообщение и запустило его обработчик?

Answer (score 1):

Просто создать окно недостаточно, ему нужен цикл обработки сообщений.

Добавил цикл и ещё несколько правок:

```
void createTrayIcon() {
    WNDCLASS cls = { 0 };
    cls.lpszClassName = TEXT("MsgWnd");
    cls.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    cls.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    RegisterClass(&cls);
    NOTIFYICONDATA data = { 0 };
    data.hWnd = CreateWindow(cls.lpszClassName, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, cls.hInstance, nullptr);
    data.uFlags = NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
    data.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    data.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER;
    _tcscpy(data.szTip, TEXT("Сервер работает"));
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &data);

    MSG msg; BOOL r;
    while ((r = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (r == -1) break;
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &data);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_USER: 
        if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            std::cout << "Icon clicked" << std::endl;
            DestroyWindow(wnd);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); // для выхода из цикла обработки сообщений
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Но в этом случае сама программа будет заблокирована пока пользователь не кликнет по иконке, т. к. будет крутить цикл обработки сообщений. Так что если во время отображения иконки программа должна что-то делать, то эту функцию (`createTrayIcon`) нужно вызывать в отдельном потоке.